# unable to connect to logstash pod deployed using helm charts from another pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I am having trouble connecting to Logstash pod which is created using helm charts by passing custom values. Added ingress along with tls cert, and added service, configured external ports and https ports which logstash listens.

The following is part of the values file with ingress and service

```
      values: |
        httpPort: 9600
        image: "docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash"
        rbac:
          create: true


        ingress:
          enabled: true
          annotations: 
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-private
            cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
          hosts:
            - host: example.com
              paths:
                - path: /logstash
                  servicePort: 9600

          tls: 
            - secretName: cert-secretname
              hosts:
                - example.com
            
            
        extraPorts:
          - name: logstash
            containerPort: 9600

        service:
          type: ClusterIP
          ports:
            - name: logstash
              protocol: TCP
              port: 9600
              targetPort: 9600
```

output of service

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP         EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
logstashpoc   ClusterIP   1.2.3.4(example)   <none>        9600/TCP
```

output of ingress

```
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS         ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
logstashpoc   <none>   example.com             80, 443
```

describe ingress output

```
Name:              logstashpoc
Namespace:         logstash-workflow
Labels:            app=logstashpoc
                   chart=logstash
                   heritage=Helm
                   release=logstashpoc-dev
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=logstashpoc,chart=logstash,heritage=Helm,release=logstashpoc-dev
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                1.2.3.4(example)
IPs:               1.2.3.4(example)
Port:              logstash  9600/TCP
TargetPort:        9600/TCP
Endpoints:         4.3.2.1:9600 (example)
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Do you have any network policy? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: No, I am getting nginx bad gateway. I am unable to connect to the logstash pod from another pod in same cluster.